# Boolean properties of the class

Tags: loops

I need to iterate through the properties of the class and check whether some of them are boolean. What is the best way to do that?

Best regards,

Comment: You need to add what language(s) you are dealing with. Probably also be a good idea to show things you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

in C# you can create instance of a class and check for booleans with the following code:

```
   var classInstance = new MyClass();
   foreach (var propertyInfo in classInstance.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
       if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
       {
           // This property is type of bool.
       }
   }
```